# Pyspark - Looping through structType and ArrayType to do typecasting in the structfield

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am quite new to pyspark and this problem is boggling me. Basically I am looking for a **scalable** way to loop typecasting through a structType or ArrayType.

Example of my data schema:

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- created: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- card_rates: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- rate_1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- rate_2: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- rate_3: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- card_fee: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- payment_method: string (nullable = true)
 |-- online_rates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- rate_1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rate_2: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- online_fee: double (nullable = true)
 |-- updated: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

As you can see here, `card_rates` is struct and `online_rates` is an array of struct. I am looking ways to loop through all the fields above and conditionally typecast them. Ideally if it is supposed to be numeric, it should be converted to double, if it is supposed to be string, It should be converted to string. I need to loop because those `rate_*` fields may grow with time.

But for now, I am content with being able to loop them and typecast all of them to string since I am very new with pyspark and still trying to get a feel of it.

My desired output schema:

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- created: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- card_rates: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- rate_1: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- rate_2: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- rate_3: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- card_fee: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- payment_method: string (nullable = true)
 |-- online_rates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- rate_1: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- rate_2: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- online_fee: double (nullable = true)
 |-- updated: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

I am running out ideas how to do this.

I got reference from here: [PySpark convert struct field inside array to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54343635/pyspark-convert-struct-field-inside-array-to-string)

but this solution hardcodes the field and does not really loop over the fields.

Kindly help.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this @addicted?

Comment: not at all :( @AlexandrosBiratsis 

Any idea for this?

Comment: I think I might have one solution, not the most elegant you could think of but it could work

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis hm always welcome to any solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one solution with the help of `StructType.simpleString` and the `_parse_datatype_string` build-in function:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df_schema = StructType([
  StructField("_id", StringType(), True),
  StructField("created", TimestampType(), True),
  StructField("card_rates", StructType([
                  StructField("rate_1", IntegerType(), True),
                  StructField("rate_2", IntegerType(), True),
                  StructField("rate_3", IntegerType(), True),
                  StructField("card_fee", IntegerType(), True),
                  StructField("card_fee", IntegerType(), True)])),
  StructField("online_rates", ArrayType(
                  StructType(
                    [
                      StructField("rate_1", IntegerType(),True),
                      StructField("rate_2", IntegerType(),True),
                      StructField("online_fee", DoubleType(),True)
                    ]),True),True),
  StructField("updated", TimestampType(), True)])

schema_str = df_schema.simpleString() # this gives -> struct<_id:string,created:timestamp,card_rates:struct<rate_1:int,rate_2:int,rate_3:int,card_fee:int, card_fee:int>,online_rates:array<struct<rate_1:int,rate_2:int,online_fee:double>>,updated:timestamp>

double_schema = schema_str.replace(':int', ':double')

# convert back to StructType
final_schema = _parse_datatype_string(double_schema)
final_schema
```

1. First convert your schema into a simple string with `schema.simpleString`
2. Then replace all `:int` with `:double`
3. Finally convert the modified string schema into StructType with `_parse_datatype_string`

**UPDATE:**

In order to avoid the issue with the backticks that @jxc pointed out a better solution would be a recursive scan through the elements as shown next:

```py
def transform_schema(schema):

  if schema == None:
    return StructType()

  updated = []
  for f in schema.fields:
    if isinstance(f.dataType, IntegerType):
      # if IntegerType convert to DoubleType
      updated.append(StructField(f.name, DoubleType(), f.nullable))
    elif isinstance(f.dataType, ArrayType):
      # if ArrayType unpack the array type(elementType), do recursion then wrap results with ArrayType 
      updated.append(StructField(f.name, ArrayType(transform_schema(f.dataType.elementType))))
    elif isinstance(f.dataType, StructType):
      # if StructType do recursion
      updated.append(StructField(f.name, transform_schema(f.dataType)))
    else:
      # else handle all the other cases i.e TimestampType, StringType etc
      updated.append(StructField(f.name, f.dataType, f.nullable))   

  return StructType(updated)

# call the function with your schema
transform_schema(df_schema)
```

*Explanation:* the function goes through each item on the schema (StructType) and tries to convert the int fields (StructField) into double. Finally delivers the converted schema (StructType) to the above layer (parent StructType).

Output:

```
StructType(List(
  StructField(_id,StringType,true),
  StructField(created,TimestampType,true),
  StructField(card_rates,
              StructType(List(StructField(rate_1,DoubleType,true),
                              StructField(rate_2,DoubleType,true),
                              StructField(rate_3,DoubleType,true),
                              StructField(card_fee,DoubleType,true),
                              StructField(card_fee,DoubleType,true))),true),
  StructField(online_rates,ArrayType(
    StructType(List(
      StructField(rate_1,DoubleType,true),
      StructField(rate_2,DoubleType,true),
      StructField(online_fee,DoubleType,true))),true),true),
  StructField(updated,TimestampType,true)))
```

**UPDATE: (2020-02-02)**

And here is one example on how to use the new schema together with the existing dataframe:

```py
updated_schema = transform_schema(df.schema)

# cast each column to the new type
select_expr = [df[f.name].cast(f.dataType) for f in updated_schema.fields]

df.select(*select_expr).show()
```

Comment: If in the next month I have rate_3 and rate_4, can this adapt to that change?

Problem is Im not the one who creates `rate_3` and `rate_4`. Some other people did that and I never know how many rates a row of data can have. That's why it has to be less hard-code.

Comment: if the rate_3 and rate_4 are int as well the above python script will convert them yes. You just need to execute it every time the schema is updated

Comment: so my data is like this. Some data has `rate_1` only, some data has `rate_1` and `rate_2`, some data has `rate_1`, `rate_2`, `rate_3`. Will that return error if it is trying to convert `rate_*` which is non-existent?

Comment: no because the above script does not depend on the column names at all. Initially you have a schema, this schema should be an instance StructType. We convert each int field to double without checking anything regarding column names. You can try to run the script line by line and see the output. If you face any issues let me know

Comment: ok I will need to try that first and see if I run into issues. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis, this will fail if any field-names contain special chars like dot, space etc. which needs to be enclosed by backticks. this is one thing we have to consider when using DDL-formatted simpleString.

Comment: @jxc can you provide an example? I can't think of any case like that. Although I think addicted was pretty much specific about the names and it seems that the above way to use replace it should work for his case

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis: `_parse_datatype_string("struct<my.col:string,b1:int>")`, while you need `_parse_datatype_string("struct<\`my.col\`:string,b1:int>")`. notice the dot in the field-name and the back-ticks which wont be added by `df.schema.simpleString()`.

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis, a more robust way is to use re.sub() to adjust the simpleString, so we can add the backtick and meanwhile map the field dtype. The same issue also to `schema_of_json()` which also returns DDL-formatted string without the backticks. However if you are sure that none field names contain special chars like dot, spaces, hyphen etc, then `str.replace()` should be enough.

Comment: I agree @jxc, to be more correct I would prefer to implement a recursive solution.

Comment: @addicted I updated the answer with a new function which is processing the elements of the schema recursively

Comment: Hi @addicted, did the above solution help finally?

Comment: Hi @alexandro sorry havent replied again. I will try within today or tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: No problem @addicted I was just wondering if this is what you were trying to implement. I updated the answer with an example about how to use it on your existing code