# Exploding struct type large number of columns to two columns of each column having keys and values in Pyspark

Tags: struct, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, explode

I have a pyspark df who's schema looks like this

```
 root
 |-- company: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- A: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- A_timestamp: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- B: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- B_timestamp: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- C: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- C_timestamp: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- D: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- D_timestamp: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- E: long(nullable = true)
 |    |-- E_timestamp: long(nullable = true)
```

I want the final format of this dataframe with 4 columns to look like this
[image]

Please help me to solve this using Pyspark.

Comment: a sample data will help here for more clear understanding

Comment: That's the sample data

Comment: can you also share how the input data looks like?

Comment: Is this the same question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62576297/type-casting-large-number-of-struct-fields-to-string-using-pyspark in a different format? did the answer to this previous question had any issue?

Comment: Yeah It's the extension of the previous Question. This is more complex than I've expected